# Need help defining message argument, not sure what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been working on a simple help command that's supposed to give in depth help with certain commands when the argument for the command is put in, if it's not put in it's supposed to throw out a general command list.

Function snippet:

```js
function help(helpcomm) {

 if (helpcomm == "say") {
  message.channel.send("Say command makes me repeat the words you type. EG. if you type `p!say Hello World!` I'm going to delete your message and say `Hello world!`.");
 } else
 if (helpcomm == "ping") {
  message.channel.send("Ping command checks the latency between me, the node I'm hosted on and the API latency.");
 } else
 if (helpcomm == "purge") {
  message.channel.send("Purge command deletes a number of latest messages you choose from 2 to 99. EG. if you type `p!purge 20` I will delete the last 20 messages.");
 } else
 if (helpcomm == "joke") {
  message.channel.send("Joke sends a random joke from my database.");
 } else
 if (helpcomm == "roll") {
  message.channel.send("Roll makes me roll a dice from 1 to 20 sides. Basically a random number generator.");
 } else
 if (helpcomm == "creator") {
  message.channel.send("Gives info about my creator. Currently outdated.");
 } else
 message.channel.send("For specific command help type: `p!help [command]` \nHere are my commands: `p!say [words], p!ping, p!purge [number], p!joke, p!roll [number], p!creator`");
}
```

And command that's supposed to take the argument:

```js
if (command === "help") {
   let text = args.join(' ');
   await message.channel.send(help(text));
  }
```

I can node the bot with no errors thrown, but when i actually input the prefix with the command with or without an argument it throws an error saying "Message not defined."

Help would be very much appriciated, if you can explain what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it that would be amazing, no spoon feeding. 
If I need to provide any additional information I will put it into comments.

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that the `message` variable does not exist in the scope of the help function. If you want to be calling message.channel.send inside your help function, then you'll need to pass message into it:

```
function help (helpComm, message) {
  if (helpcomm == "say") {
    return message.channel.send("Say command makes me repeat the words you type. [etc]');
  }
  //...
  return message.channel.send("For specific command help [etc]")
}

// called like:

client.on('message', async function(message) {
  //...
  if (command === "help") {
    let text = args.join(' ');
    await help(text, message);
  }
});
```

That said though, It's not clear to me that that's what you intend to do, since this line is already calling message.channel.send, and is apparently expecting help to return a string:

```
await message.channel.send(help(text));
```

If you just want help to produce a string, then there's no need to pass message to it, since only the main code needs to interact with the message object:

```
function help (helpComm) {
  if (helpcomm == "say") {
    return "Say command makes me repeat the words you type. [etc]';
  }
  // ...
  return "For specific command help [etc]";
}

// called like:

client.on('message', async function(message) {
  //...
  if (command === "help") {
    let text = args.join(' ');
    await message.channel.send(help(text));
  }
});
```

Comment: I have a message handler already, something along the lines of this: 
`client.on("message", async message => {

const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const command = args.shift();

  if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;` 

I just don't know why the message says not defined.. when I put help(helpcomm, message) it throws:

 "TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined".

 I'm so lost on how to fix this